# Can we create a list template without creating a list first in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I know how to create a list template by creating from an existing list.

Can we create a new list template from the scratch without creating a list first?  If so, any brief steps?

Can I delete the list after a list template is created from the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom list definition and package it as a feature. The main item you will be creating is a schema.xml that will define your List.

Here is a tutorial

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466023.aspx

Its not trivial, but once you've managed it you'll have a good understanding of the various artifacts involved in storing data in SharePoint, e.g. Content Types, Fields, Views etc.

Best of luck,
Shane